# import & Export all categories in csv format

Tags: php, magento, import, export, categories

how can I import and export all categories in magento with csv format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Mass Product Importer - Magmi Project

The magmi project initial goal was to provide a product mass import script from csv files that match magento
dataflow csv export format.

The main project goal is to achieve dataflow like operations with a reasonable speed.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/

Answer (score 1):

This [forum post](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewreply/189912/) on the Magento website takes you through the process.  It adds a new Adapter to import categories via the Magento importer.  This is the recommended approach rather than using raw SQL due to the complex joins and indexes.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know about exporting it.I only know how to import it.
To importing category:
1. Create Advanced Profile and paste the code written by santosh kumar from this forum http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/26022/ and save it.

1. I get blank admin page while running it,so need to modify dataflow.xml from adminhtml/default/default/layout/ `<adminhtml_system_convert_profile_run>
     <remove name = "root"/>
     <block type="adminhtml/page" name="convert_root" output="toHtml" template="page.phtml">
           <block type="adminhtml/page_head" name="convert_root_head" as="head" template="page/head.phtml">
               <action method="addJs"><script>prototype/prototype.js</script></action>
               <action method="addJs"><script>prototype/validation.js</script></action>
               <action method="addJs"><script>varien/js.js</script></action>
               <action method="addJs"><script>mage/translate.js</script></action>
               <action method="addJs"><script>mage/adminhtml/tools.js</script></action>
         </block>
         <block type="adminhtml/system_convert_profile_run" name="system_convert_profile_run" template="system/convert/profile/process.phtml" output="toHtml"/>
     </block>
   </adminhtml_system_convert_profile_run>`
   and flush magento cash, Now you can see profile executes. One more thing you need to create categories.csv in var/import folder and in which you have to write `store,categories
   default,Sports
   default,Sports/Cricket
   default,Sports/Tenis`.

Comment: store,categories in a new line theb default,Sports in a new line and continue for doing like this to add categories.

Comment: AS i said its working only for importing,not for exporting!! Does it work for you? And do you know how to export it?

Comment: Have Created? U got any solution for exporting?

Answer (score 1):

I used Magmi for Mass products import products it is good for fast products import but there are many issues we have to fix it to make it work.
Now i am looking for Import Export Categories code but i am unable to find it then i got Import Export Categories extension,http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/import-export-categories-extension.html
It works great. Easy to install and work as per my requirements. fully satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works for me. Please check the following link for full code.
https://www.pearlbells.co.uk/export-woocommerce-categories-csv/

```
function getCategories() {
wp_reset_query();
$custom_terms = get_terms('product_cat');
$allData = array();
foreach( $custom_terms as $custom_term ) {

    $categoryData = array( $custom_term->term_id, $custom_term->parent, $custom_term->name, $custom_term->slug, $custom_term->description  );
    $seoData = yoastSeoDetails( $custom_term->term_id );
    $featuredImage = getCategoryImage( $custom_term->term_id  );
    $allData[$custom_term->term_id] = array_merge( $categoryData, $seoData, $featuredImage );
}
createCSV($allData);
}

function getCategoryImage( $catId ) {

$thumbnail_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $catId, 'thumbnail_id', true ); 
$catImageUrl = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumbnail_id );    
return array($catImageUrl);
```

}